# block code in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command

I don't understand what's the problem with the syntax of this script:

```
@echo off
set a=1
set b=2
cd d:\
if %a% equ 1 (
  set a=%b%
  set b=5
  echo in a: %a%
  echo in b: %b%
  )
echo out a: %a%
echo out b: %b%
pause
exit /b
```

I get this result:

```
in a: 1
in b: 2
out a: 2
out a: 5
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
in a: 2  
in b: 5
out a: 2
out a: 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a batch file is executed, the lines/blocks are parsed, executed, and the process continues in the next line/block. When the parser reaches a line or block of code, all the `%variable%` references are replaced with the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute the code. So, if you change the value of a variable inside a block of code, this new value is not accesible from inside the same block of code: the read operation to the variable does not exist, it was replaced with the value inside the variable.

You need to enable delayed expansion and, where needed, change the syntax to access the value in the variable from `%var%` to `!var!`. This indicates to the parser that the read operation should be delayed until the read operation is executed.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set a=1
    set b=2
    cd d:\
    if %a% equ 1 (
      set a=%b%
      set b=5
      echo in a: !a!
      echo in b: !b!
      )
    echo out a: %a%
    echo out b: %b%
    pause
    exit /b
```